# I amt trying to dismiss my tableViewController in override func tableView(...didSelectRowAt...), but nothing happens

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I want to return to my previous viewController, so I used the dismiss method, but when I select a cell nothing happens. This is the code that I have right now.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtindexPath: IndexPath) {


            delegate?.dataReceived(data: universityArray[indexPath.row].name)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Do you use UITableViewDelegate? Is your class inherited from UIViewController or UITableViewController? Also check that if you set the delegate like `tableView.delegate = self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the top of my head, i can see two potential problems here

1. The `tableView` delegate is not set

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

2. The viewController was not presented rather pushed, of that is the case try `popViewController` instead of `dismiss`

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Hope the problem was one of the above.

Comment: I didn't present the view modally